# How do I put different images in rightBarButtonItem when I click on cell in xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, rightbarbuttonitem

How can I change the image in the right button of the navigation bar when I select a specific cell?

A good example is in the picture where the `rightBarButtonItem` image is different based on the selected cell:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a right bar button item in the navigation bar with this code in the viewDidLoad:

```
let navBarbutton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.bookmarks, target: self, action: nil)
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = navBarbutton
```

(change the systemItem with your image)

Add an IBOutlet like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
```

and connect it to the navigation item in your storyboard.

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can handle it with this sample code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: nil)
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.camera, target: self, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to creating and set `UIBarButtonItem` as `navigationItem`.

```
let updateButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: YourImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = updateButton

@objc func buttonAction() {
}
```

So in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath` delegate method according to condition create and set `UIBarButtonItem` as required.